# Import CSV and write into SQL Server database with sequalize node.js

Tags: node.js, sql-server, sequelize.js, etl

I wrote a script that iterates over many `.CSV` files and (should) send the data with sequelize to a SQL Server database. I use `csv-parse` module to read and 'cast' the data, meaning that it reduces the data to its smallest datatype.

ISSUE: In order to send the data to the DB, I need to define a `Model` object, that defines the format and datatypes of the table. I want this to be automated and based on the 'casted' csv.

Additional issue: I want to be able to upsert the table too eventually.

I have accomplished to:

- Connect to the DB with sequelize and verify the connection (also did a test query)
- Read the CSVs and 'cast' the data. It recognises integers, floats and even dates. It also accepts the header that I parsed to the csv module.

I am a novice with js and I feel that I am not grasping something fundamental here. In python and pandas this would be a simple single line. All help would be much appreciated!

Comment: Take a look at ORM frameworks.

Comment: @Hamed_gibago, I have.. do you know how to infer a data-model based on a CSV import (basically a JS object with key-value pairs per row).

Comment: What's the purpose of node.js? Can you not just do a bulk insert?

Comment: Hi @ASH, I want something lightweight to handle this operation, preferably something that could also work in the context of a serverless function, say a lambda of azure function. I have been doing most of the data-handling with NodeJS thus far. Do you have recommendations?

Comment: I'm not sure what a serverless function is, but I would do a Bulk Insert, if I had to do this. https://blog.sqlauthority.com/2008/02/06/sql-server-import-csv-file-into-sql-server-using-bulk-insert-load-comma-delimited-file-into-sql-server/

Comment: @ASH, so the serverless function is a small runtime environment that runs in the cloud. Ideally, it has some logic that enables it to do deal with multiple scenario's. Overall, the process should be to load CSV's into a DB. The scenarios are:
1. New table; I need to create the table and load in the data
2. Table already exists; I need to add the new records
3. The table might have changed (e.g. a new column has been added), I change the table and add the records. 
So you want an interative process that can deal with permutations of the data-model. Does that make any sense?

Comment: Well, #1 and #2 are easily accomplished with Bulk Insert. As for #3, I think you're going to go nuts very quickly if your table structure, and overall schema, is changing. If that's the case, I'd recommend using Python and df.to_sql. Here's a link that may help. https://datatofish.com/pandas-dataframe-to-sql/

Comment: The benefit of using data frames to push data into a sql table is that if the schema changes, the data frame will adjust dynamically, and it will push the data to the table dynamically (if columns exist, the data gets appended underneath existing data and if columns are new, they are dynamically added, off to the right.)

https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/merging.html

Comment: @ASH, true that, the pandas method is WAY easier. So basically your are saying, dont do it node.js. That resolves my problem :) Thanks!